# interface orientation not correct in presented view controllers in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

in iOS 7 and earlier, I was able to make UI changes in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation) ) {

        //update views for landscape

    }

    else {

        //update views for portrait

    }

}
```

I can still do this in iOS 8 **except** in view controllers that are presented by other view controllers. When a view controller is presented by another view controller, this does not work, because the `self.interfaceOrientation` property is not correct in the presented view controller. It does not reflect the current orientation, but rather the orientation right before the device rotation.

The issue is not present if presenting a view controller on iPad with `modalPresentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`. In other words, the issue is only present when presenting a full screen view controller.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```

Also, if you are dropping support for iOS 7 and going 8-only, I recommend you drop interface orientation handling in favor of trait collections and size classes, if you can.

Comment: This is great. It's just so annoying that there are so many little issues with iOS 8 like this one.

Comment: Yes, but I think they will improve things as we try to write more device-agnostic apps in the future. Much of the stuff in iOS 8 is about fixing stuff that was done weird or wrong the first time around.